# MS access date validation rules

Tags: validation, date, ms-access

I have 2 fields: birthdate and registered date. I want to set a validation rule on Registered date so that the date entered here is always later then the birthdate. It should be something like this: Date([registered date])>Date([birthdate]) .
But then I get the error: "The expression you entered has a function containing the wrong number of arguments."

How do I solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Date()` returns the current date; it does not accept an argument.  Perhaps you want `DateValue()`  but, if `[registered date]` and `[birthdate]` are both Access Date/Time datatype, you can compare their values directly without the need of a function: `[registered date]>[birthdate]`

Comment: I tried that, but now I get: Invalid SQL Syntax - cannot use multiple columns
in a column-level CHECK constraint.

Comment: http://imgur.com/gallery/Le1cXeF/new

Comment: Open the table's property sheet and add your Validation Rule there.

Answer (score 0):

Set the validation rule for `registered date` to: `>[birthdate]`